# How to export fitted surface Curve Fitting Toolbox to matrix?

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

Matlab Curve Fitting Toolbox.
I need to export new coordinates of fitted surface XYZ.

Comment: You can get the model equation and the coefficient values from the fit object as shown [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/evaluate-a-surface-fit.html#d119e14829). Then you should be able to evaluate the surface for the known `X` and `Y` values

Comment: Thanks a lot
I don’t understand, how to evaluate the surface
Can you write the code?

Comment: Can you include the code that you already have?

Comment: ziData = feval(fitresult,[xData,yData])

Comment: problem solved 
thanks

Comment: save data to workspace in curve fitting tool
after that
ziData = feval(fitresult,[xData,yData])